# How to detect where "down" is with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientation, screen-orientation

I am trying to have a 2D arrow on a page that is always facing down, i.e. if I rotate my phone sideways it will still be facing down.
[image: Demo image]

I have already tried reading the information provided by the `deviceorientation` event (alpha, beta, gamma), but I can't find out how to use these measurements to find out where "down" is.
I tried using alpha only but this only works in specific orientations.

How should I combine alpha, beta and gamma to get the angle to "down"?